# Image not being sent to NodeJS api from ReactJs redux-saga using yield call()

Tags: reactjs, node.js, redux-saga

This is my saga function:-

```
// Sagas for Update Profile Starts //
function* updateProfileStartHandlerSaga(action){
    try
    {
        console.log(action.payload)
        const {data} = yield call(apiClient.post, '/api/v1/user/update-profile', action.payload)
        if(data?.success === true)
        {
            yield put({type : types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS, payload : data})
        }
        else
        {
            yield put({type : types.UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR, payload : data.message})
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        yield put({type : types.UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR, payload : err})
    }
}
export function* updateProfileStartWatcherSaga(){
    yield takeEvery(types.UPDATE_PROFILE_START, updateProfileStartHandlerSaga)
}
// Sagas for Update Profile Ends //
```

The loc `console.log(action.payload)` shows that the payload has the image data as well.

[image]

But when the request is made to the node js server, the `image` data is blank object. See the below screenshot.

[image]

I even tried to use formData, but still nothing happes.

```
try
{
    var formData = new FormData(action.payload);
    const {data} = yield call(apiClient.post, '/api/v1/user/update-profile', formData )
    if(data?.success === true)
    {
        yield put({type : types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS, payload : data})
    }
    else
    {
        yield put({type : types.UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR, payload : data.message})
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?